# How to create a copy of nn.Sequential in torch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to create a copy of a [nn.Sequential](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html#torch.nn.Sequential) network. For example, the following is the easiest way to do the same-

```
net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(),
    )

net_copy = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(),
    )
```

However, it is not so great to define the network again. I tried the following ways but it didn't work-

1. `net_copy = nn.Sequential(net)`: In this approach, it seems that `net_copy` is just a shared pointer of `net`
2. `net_copy = nn.Sequential(*net.modules())`: In this approach, `net_copy` contains many more layers.

Finally, I tired `deepcopy` in the following way which worked fine-

```
net_copy = deepcopy(net)
```

However, I am wondering if it is the proper way. I assume it is fine because it works.

Comment: do you wish to keep the weights or do you want a new model with the same architecture?

Comment: @skinny_func: I want a new model with the same architecture. I guess `deepcopy` is doing the same.

Comment: `deepcopy` should be fine. You could also create function which copies parameters and buffers from one network to another after creating an instance of your network.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke: I think so too. `deepcopy` works fine. Probably it is the easiest way and clean too! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just use `torch.load` and `torch.save` with `io.BytesIO`

```
import io, torch


# write to a buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO()
torch.save(model, buffer) #<--- model is some nn.module
print(buffer.tell()) #<---- no of bytes written 

del model

# read from buffer
buffer.seek(0) #<--- must see to origin every time before reading
model = torch.load(buffer)
del buffer
```